# Javascript resizing a container to an image size

Tags: javascript

I have a little bit of JS code that is causing me some issues.

I have a div which i called image-window it is using bootstrap class col-xs-8, i need it to hold an image, but the image size is dynamic, so i did was create another container called img-container.

What I am trying to do is make sure that if the image (img-container) is bigger than the image-window then force the img-container to the same size as the image-window.

What i have only works some of the time though ... I think that if the image takes longer to load than the page, it doesn't seem to work and i have to press refresh a few times to get it to properly size it.

Below is what i have, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var originalWidth = $('#image-window').width();

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'https://websitehere.com/fboQ2uivUPqBqTyi0ZtiPq.jpg';
        img.onload = function () {
            var newContainerWidth = img.width;
            if ( originalWidth >= newContainerWidth ) {
                $("#img-container").width( newContainerWidth );
            }
        };

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I’d recommend using `img.onload` as soon as possible, right after `var img = new Image();`; also, instead of `img.onload` consider `img.addEventListener("load", function(){`…`})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding what you want, you shouldn't need any js at all. By default, images just take up their native resolution in width, causing it to be larger than its container. You can easily fix this by seeing a `max-width: 100%` on the img.

I made an example below. The first img has no max-width setting, but the second one (which is in a container of width 25%) does.

```css
.huge-image-contained {
  width: 25%;
}

.huge-image-contained img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="huge-image">
  <img src="http://78.media.tumblr.com/f5b9e422f92d6a69974b402f106d58bd/tumblr_n6qzvaD2PO1tddya3o1_1280.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="huge-image-contained">
  <img src="http://78.media.tumblr.com/f5b9e422f92d6a69974b402f106d58bd/tumblr_n6qzvaD2PO1tddya3o1_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are not using `css` to accomplish this?
Built into `css` is a function as follows:

```
  #idofimage {
  width: 100%;
  }

  #Or use class if this is dynamic

  .idofimage {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

This will go in your main `style.css` file which is called in the top of your page by a `<meta>` tag or simply in a `<style> //code </style>` fashion.
This will ensure that the image is always 100% of the container width which is your `<div>` tag the image is put in.

There are many other `css styles` but using `javascript` to resize images is technical whilst tools like `css` make life much easier.

Comment: In my opinion, setting `width: 100%` to images in any type of dynamic context is a bad idea. Scaling up images, unless svgs, often times looks bad. I think max-width is a better solution unless the design calls for it to always be exactly the width of the container, even if natively the resolution is smaller